# Minimum possible tread depth for shaved tire?

Tags: tires, subaru, forester, replacements

Once again I have to replace a tire on my Forester (3rd tire in 3 years!  I'm a magnet for damage).  I have the stock Bridgestone Ecopia H/L 422 Plus with about 23,000 miles on them.  I just measured the tread depth of the doomed tire, and saw 11/64" in about 5 locations - so feel that is a representative depth.

The question is then at what minimum depth can you get shaved tires?  Is matching 11/64" possible? (If not, I'm looking a 4 new tires .. grrr .. should I just do that instead?)

Comment: Who cares?  Just match the most direct drive tires as close as you can and call it good.  All your differentials have flex for differing tire diameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a competent tire shop (one which can shave your tires), you can get them whatever depth you need them at. Getting one tire to 11/64" should be no issue, as that is actually a lot of tread depth. Minimum tread depth is 2/32" (IIRC). Just take it there and have them match it. You'll have to figure out which shop to take it to, obviously, but they are out there.

Don't get a complete new set if you have 11/64" on the other three ... just get one and have it shaved. You are on the right track to begin with.

Comment: @PeterM - I went and checked ... minimum tread depth is 2/32", which still leaves you a bunch of tread to go from 11/64".